# How to enable dynamic client in hosts.allowed for SSH?

Tags: ssh, hosts, dyndns, dynamic-ip

I'm using a `hosts.allowed` for SSH. Now, some people have dynamic IPs but they also have dyndns.com hosts. How could I use a dyndns.com like host to /etc/hosts ?

(The server is a Debian 5.0 Lenny amd64)
(Changing to SSH key auth and so on is not a way.)

Comment: What exactly is "/etc/hosts based SSH auth"?

Comment: When you put host files who are allowed to connect to the PC. But yea I messed up. hosts.allowed .. I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the DynDNS host names pointing to the clients' IP addresses to your `/etc/hosts.allow` file instead of literal IP addresses. See `man 5 hosts_access`.